# Wild swimming near Bologna

Tags: italy, swimming, bologna

Where is it possible to swim in the wild near Bologna? I'm not looking for swimming pools but something like lakes or certain river spots.

Answer (score 3):

I don't recall of any impressive lake near Bologna; however, if you are fine with driving a little further you could find some rivers and beautiful waterfalls near the border of *Tuscany*.

Here are few:

[*Cascata di Moraduccio*](https://www.tripadvisor.it/Attraction_Review-g2250952-d8599375-Reviews-Cascata_di_Moraduccio-Castel_del_Rio_Province_of_Bologna_Emilia_Romagna.html), ~60KM from Bologna, located in Tuscany, right at the border with Emilia-Romagna

[*Cascate del Golfarone*](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g2282841-d10260633-Reviews-Cascata_del_Golfarone-Villa_Minozzo_Province_of_Reggio_Emilia_Emilia_Romagna.html), ~100KM from Bologna, in Emilia-Romagna

[*Cascata dell’Acquacheta*](https://www.tripadvisor.it/Attraction_Review-g4923095-d6280980-Reviews-Cascata_dell_Acquacheta-San_Benedetto_in_Alpe_Province_of_Forli_Cesena_Emilia_Ro.html), ~105KM from Bologna.

[*Fiume Ceno*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceno).

You can find more suggestions in this [blog](http://ecobnb.it/blog/2016/07/piscine-naturali-emilia-romagna/).